# Mechanical Turk - Fetch all information of batches in one go.

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

Is there any way to fetch all the information from different batches in one go. Say for example I have published 50 batches in last 6 months and wish to download the CSV file result of all those batches in one file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can only download them batch-by-batch. You could access all the HITs individually via the API, which would probably be easier in this case than manually downloading 50 CSVs.